# Custom Facet for Anonymous Contact. Is it possible?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics, experience-profile, contact-facets

**Hi guys,**

I have a fairly simple question. I have created some `custom facets` and tested them for `known` Contacts and they work. But when I do the same regarding `Anonymous` Contacts, I could not set the `custom facets` being set on it.

[image: anonymous facets on db]

I could not find anything in Sitecore documentation about it. Do you think it is even possible?

Here is my code for getting the contact for `known` and `anonymous` contact:

```
string contactId = CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N");
        var trackerIdentifier = IsAnonymous ? new IdentifiedContactReference(Constants.IdentifierSource, contactId) 
            : new IdentifiedContactReference(ContactSource, Identifier);

        using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var facets = new string[]
                {
                    PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey,
                    ServiceabilityFacet.DefaultFacetKey,
                    CustomerAttributesFacet.DefaultFacetKey
                };

                return client.Get<Contact>(trackerIdentifier, new ContactExpandOptions(facets));
            }
            catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Could not load contact by identifier {contactId}", ex, this);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the anonymous contact saved? Also, can you save any of the built-in facets?

Comment: Yes the anonymous contact is saved. And the built-in PersonalInformation facet fields like first name and last name is also saved.

Comment: Are you sure that your custom model json file is copied to XConnect?

Comment: 100% possible. Do it all the time. Can you post your facet saving code. That is more important than the getting code.

Comment: Of course, it is possible. It doesn't matter is your contact anonymous or known. Did you save contact changes with client.Submit()? Check log files for xconnect errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can save custom facets for Anonymous contact as well.

I have written a blog for creating and save custom facets, please refer both the blogs and verify if you missed anything.

- [Create Custom Facet Model in Sitecore 9](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/create-custom-facet-model-in-sitecore-9.html)
- [Work with Custom Facet in Sitecore 9](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/work-with-custom-facet-in-sitecore-9.html)

A method `CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs()` in `Sitecore.Analytics interface`, it is used to make your contact from Unknown (Anonymous) to Known.

Let me know in case you need further help.

Comment: Thank you! This one worked. :)